# Laravel Custom Validation Rules

Tags: php, laravel, custom-validators

I am studying the Framework Laravel and am really enjoying it, however I'm having a little problem in the "Validator". I need to make a custom rule. I searched the documentation and in some sites on the internet and managed to do so:

1º I created a folder called "app / validators /"

2º I created a file called "CpfValidation.php" inside that folder with a class.

3º In the file "app / start / global.php" I included the line:

```
app_path (). '/ validators'
```

4 In my controller I insert the code:

```
Validator::extend('validaCpf', 'CpfValidation@validaCpf');

$validacao = Validator::make(

    array(
        'nome_completo' => Input::get('nome_completo'),
        'cpf'           => Input::get('cpf'),
        'email'         => Input::get('email'),
        'telefone'      => Input::get('telefone'),
        'logradouro'    => Input::get('logradouro'),
        'estado'        => Input::get('estado')
    ),

    array(
        'nome_completo' => 'required|min:2',
        'cpf'           => 'required|validaCpf',
        'email'         => 'required|email',
        'telefone'      => 'required|min:14',
        'logradouro'    => 'required',
        'estado'        => 'required'
    ),

    array(
        'nome_completo.required' => 'Você não informou o seu nome!',
        'nome_completo.min'      => 'O seu nome deve ter pelo menos 2 letras!',
        'cpf.required'           => 'Você não informou o seu CPF!',
        'cpf.validaCpf'          => 'O CPF informado não parece ser válido!',
        'email.required'         => 'Você não informou o seu e-mail!',
        'email.email'            => 'O e-mail informado não parece ser válido!',
        'telefone.required'      => 'Você não informou o seu telefone!',
        'telefone.min'           => 'O Telefone informado não parece ser válido!',
        'logradouro.required'    => 'Você não informou o seu endereço!',
        'estado.required'        => 'Você não informou o seu estado!'
    )

);
```

However when running, everything works fine, except that despite validaCpf work, does not display the message I wanted. It only displays: "validation.valida_cpf" instead "O CPF informado não parece ser válido!"

Comment: `validaCpf` is not the same as `validaCPF`. Try using the same casing on both places.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it did not work, I edited my code but still the same thing.

Comment: Where is `CpfValidation@validaCpf` ? Post the code and what is the error ?

Comment: "CpfValidation" is a Class and "validaCpf" is a method of this Class. This class is in "app/validators/CpfValidation.php", it's working fine but don't show the message. I tasted the method sending valid and invalid data. When I sending valid data, the error message is not display, but when I send invalid data, is showed "validation.valida_cpf". I belive which the error don't is in class, because I have used this class in other application in other context and work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the messages function to apply your own message content.
For example check this:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'title.required' => 'A title is required',
        'body.required' => 'A message is required',
    ];
}
```

You can found it in the official Laravel5.1 documentation
[Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation) check this paragraph **Customizing The Error Messages**